# Signal Processing on Android, memory issues?

Tags: android, memory

I have 30 minutes of EEG data which I loop through using a 200 sample length sliding window, each window is wavelet transformed, features are extracted and it is classified. This results in about 3500 windows where each window loops through 200 values.

Hence the loop looks something like this:

while( shift < 3500*100){

```
    // GET 200 SAMPLES
    for (int i=starter; i<wl+shift; i++) {

    v = dis.readFloat();
        data[i] = v;
        }
    // SHIFT FOR NEXT LOOP
      shift = shift + 100;
      starter = shift;

  // EXTRACT FEATURES

    Transform t = new Transform( new FastWaveletTransform( new Daub04( ) ) );


   double[ ] arrTime = data;

    final double[ ] arrHilb = t.forward( arrTime ); // 1-D FWT Haar forward


    // coeff1
        for (int j = 0; j < length/2; j++) {

           coeff1[j] = arrHilb[length-1-j];
            sum1 += coeff1[j];
                }
```

It processes for about 20 mins and then fails (skipping frames). In Matlab it takes a few seconds with array operations, but I cant see any other way to do it on Android than this.

The idea is just to segmentate the EEG data into 200 sample chunks with a 50% overlap and extract features for each.

UPDATE SOLVED:
    The problem was in the way the data arrays were constructed from read.Float and looped through. I ended up reading the entire dataset into the array data, then another loop which shifts data 200 samples by using System.arraycopy(data, starter, data1, 0, data1.length); and have starter = starter + 200 for each iteration. It is done in a matter of seconds, so no worries :)

Thanks!

Comment: post the `adb logcat` log, please.

Comment: Pardon the ugly wall of text, not sure how to format it here. I wonder if it helps using an asynctask to handle it, but still the amount of time it uses seems inefficient.

Comment: _how to format:_ either 4 spaces or a tab in the beginning of each line. In gedit, I select all and press Tab to indent the selection.

Comment: 1) `Skipped 37387 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` -- looks like a "fool recursion". 2) What is on the line `MainActivity.java:112` ? (This is the only reported line that is yours.)

Comment: Actually 112 is a blank space, it is like this:

    111:       for (int i=starter; i<wl+shift; i++) {
    112:
    113:            v = dis.readFloat();

Also, I've run the code on "small scale" by setting the while limit to match e.g. 10 iterations where it works, it just runs rather slow

Comment: Please post the code of the function around MainActivity.java:112 (it's onCreate(), I believe). The fact that it is blank space most likely means that you have inserted or deleted a line since obtaining the log.

Comment: Wait actually the i-loop for reading data might be wrong, data[i] isn't cleared at any point as just keeps on getting fed information as i is shifted, instead of acting as a 200 sample chunk. Maybe that will fix it.

The code around line 112 starts right after the //GET 200 SAMPLES comment in the code I've posted, hope it helps

Comment: Yeah the problem was in the loop, doesn't have anything to do with the processing, it finishes in a couple of seconds now :) thanks!